# regex of any word not preceeded by a period

Tags: c#, regex

I've tried several options, but nothing is giving me the whole word.

this gives me partial words,

```
`@"(?<![.])\w+"`
```

I'm parsing c# code, so the string `"Regex.Match(" ", " ")"` should return Regex but not Match.

I've ended up using just `\w+` and doing this check,

```
if ((match.Index > 0) && ('.' == text[match.Index - 1]))
    continue;
```

Which works fine, but was just curious if there is a regex that would do it as well.

Comment: Is it me that didn't understand your question correctly or you said `I am parsing C# code with Regex`? I hope it's me that didn't understand it correctly.

Comment: Could you give us an example of the partial words your first regex is spitting out?

Comment: @Darin I'm putting color to the code posted on my website.

Comment: @Samir The regex pattern I posted would turn `.Match` into `atch`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try: `(?<![.])\b\w+\b`

Comment: I was almost there, just needed the \b's - nice!

Answer (score 1):

try this one with zero-width negative lookbehind assertion

```
(?<!(\.\w*))\w+
```

what it does is it selects only strings made of only word characters with length of at least one character which aren't preceded by strings of 0 or more word characters preceded by a dot character

more on this and other more tricky regexps in .NET @[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion)

Comment: Passes all my tests - nice work!  Can't tell who answered first, the other guy could use the points - thanks!